# What does error code LZO_E_LOOKBEHIND_OVERRUN mean?

Tags: c++, error-code, lzo

I am attempting to decompress some compressed data, but I'm getting an error code of `LZO_E_LOOKBEHIND_OVERRUN`. What does this error mean?

I have checked comments in the source code and several results on Google but I can't find what it means.

I am using LZO 1x 999 compression and [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/lzo/lzo1x_decompress_safe.c) decompression function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2011-May/035747.html

> Can't say much more about this than lzo-2.05/doc/LZOAPI.TXT [1] does:
>
> LZO_E_LOOKBEHIND_OVERRUN
> Your data is corrupted.